# google api 1.5 android

Tags: android

how to download Google API 1.5 for android SDK using Eclipse if it is not in the available packages ????

Comment: 1.5 is run on less than ~3% of devices now, I guess there deprecating it. Why would you want to develop against it? :-)

Comment: just because i have and HTC mobile 1.5 and i want to run on it gps so i want to simulate my code with Google api 1.5 to work with my mobile

Answer (score 3):

Because my first Android dev device is Hero (Android 1.6), I never downloaded Android 1.5 SDK. I just checked the SDK Manager, Google API 3 is still in Available packages. This is the screenshot of my SDK Manager:

[image]

You can find that in "Available packages" -> "Third party Add-ons" -> "Google Inc." -> "Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 3, revision 3". Please check again:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set up the SDK, 1.5 probably isn't in your available packages because it's already in your installed packages. Just try creating a new project that targets 1.5 and see if it's there.

Comment: look in your installed packages, is it there? You may just want to do a clean reinstall of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at the wrong place. The SDKs are not installed using "Install new software ..." that you used to install the ADT plugin. After installing it you must open in "Window"->"Android SDK and AVD Manager". From there clicking on "Available packages" and on the right pane on the "Android Repository" arrow should open all the available SDKs. There you can find "SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4". If you can not see the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" from within Eclipse you have not configured the ADT plugin (Eclipse preferences inside Android option) to use your base SDK files (those must be installed manually and then enter where you installed them).